# Schur multiplier for product of groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In the book The Schur multiplier by Karpilovsky, Theorem 2.2.10 says ,

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two finite groups then the Schur multiplier $$M(G_1\times G_2)=M(G_1)\times M(G_2)\times (G_1\otimes G_2).$$

But I was studying a research article https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11308, in which it is given that $$M(G_1\times G_2)=M(G_1)\times M(G_2)\times (\frac{G_1}{G_1'}\otimes \frac{G_2}{G_2'}).$$

> My question is that which result I should follow?

Comment: The second one is correct· I think that the definition by Karpilovsky of the tensor product of two groups gives the same result as the second definition. He is not talking about what is now known as the nonabelian tensor prodcut of groups, he is talking about the abelian tensor product.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Derek Holt sir, the book "The Schur multiplier" was written a in $1987$ and the result mentioned in the book was proved by Schur in $1907$ whether the notion of non abelian tensor square was given by Brown and Loudy again in $1987$. Therefore second result should be considered in general.